# One wire protocol in SIM800 through bit banging

Tags: c, embedded, bit-manipulation

Is it possible to implement `one wire protocol` in **SIM800** through `bit banging`? Time required to change the **direction of pin** (as input or output) is **1.5 microsecond** and Time required to change the **state of pin** (as low or high) is **1.5 microsecond.**

Comment: what is your baud rate for communication ?

Comment: I am using basic standard-speed

Comment: check the time on DSO as after how much time `SIM800` responds for simple `AT`, but anyway its not good idea in case you want reliable communication, as you may need to handle Call or SMS which can come at any time

Comment: that doesn't bother my project....

Comment: how will you decide when to switch communication line ? as every `AT` command has different response timeouts. I will say it is possible but not at all reliable

Comment: I have taken care of that..

Comment: Yous should provide a link to the device - I presume that is the mobile modem I found. However, you will have to try yourself, even _if_ someone tells you it will work. If bit-banding will work, more depends on your host. It might however, eat up most processing ressources and will require your whole software to be written carefully to allow proper timing.

Comment: Do you mean "1-Wire" ( Maxim/Dallas Semiconductor trade-mark)? Add a link to the part and the protocol or at least the data sheet you are reporting these timings from.

Comment: I'm voting to close that question, as he does not provide enough information to answer properly.

Answer (score 1):

The Dallas/Maxim 1-Wire(tm) protocol is self-clocking; it is deliberately designed to make it easy to implement in this way.  Using a hardware timer would be a good idea - removing a good deal of software overhead, but even a low-precision RC oscillator is likely to be accurate enough.

1-Wire(tm) is self-clocking so I assume the timings you suggest are minimum timings, not required timing; the protocol has wide tolerances for the actual bit timing, and the inter-bit timing merely requires that the line is high for >1us, but may be any length.  It only needs to be long enough to be able to detect a definite edge - on an input-capture timer or edge triggered interrupt for example - you could software poll the line, but if your application needs to get other work done at the same time, a 1us pulse may get missed.

It is not clear to me what the definition of the timings you suggest are, but if they simply refer to the duration of the edge, the 1.5us you suggest is not a software issue - that is down to the slew-rate of the I/O pin which is largely a function of the line characteristics.  For short distance communication, you'd have to really mess up the hardware design to get switching that slow.

Comment: @Olaf : I have no idea about the chip.  The "1-Wire" protocol is trade-marked by Dallas/Maxim.  The question refers to "one wire" - which may or may not refer to "1-Wire(tm)", it may refer to a "1-Wire(tm)" compatible system that uses the name to avoid trade-mark infringement, or it may be something else entirely.  The only references I can find to "SIM800" do not even mention such an interface, only UART and I2C.  Consequently I chose to assume he meant 1-Wire and just answered the question in the summary and largely ignored the body.